# How do I create a secondary index in my Amplify schema?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify

In one of the tables being generated by my amplify schema, I want to create an index to be used by a lambda to query; not actually anything in GraphQL.

I've tried adding a `@connection` directive, but then get `Could not find an object type named String.`

I'd rather do it in a config file so I can commit to git.  What is the appropriate way to do this?